# PHP copy() — No such file or directory

Tags: php, file, copy, warnings

I trying to copy file

```
copy('../'.$page['addr'], './backup/'.$page['suf'].date("_Y_m_d_h_i_s").'.html');
```

And get — Warning: copy(../company.html) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
But

```
opendir('./backup');
```

and

```
file_get_contents('../'.$page['addr']);
```

in this file, works fine. 
Wtf?

Comment: './backup/' is not writable.

Answer (score 0):

As './backup/' might not be writable. Try this on Shell to change owner to apache user:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data ./backup
```